# How can I embed an image on each of my subplots in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

I'm trying to put a little arrow in the corner of each of my subplots. Below is the sample code I'm using:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as image
from numpy import linspace

xs = linspace(0, 1, 100)
im = image.imread('arrow.png')

def multi_plot():
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(4, 1)
    x = 0
    for axis in axes:
        axis.plot(xs, xs**2)
        axis.imshow(im, extent=(0.4, 0.6, .5, .7), zorder=-1, aspect='auto')
    plt.show()

multi_plot()
```

Unfortunately, this produces 4 subplots that are entirely dominated by the arrows and the plots themselves are not seen.

Example output - Incorrect:

[image: Example output - Incorrect]

What do I need to do so that each individual subplot has a *small* image and the plot itself can be seen?

Comment: Just to mention, matplotlib can draw arrows itself. So there are easier ways to include an arrow in a plot than placing an image. Placing images makes probably more sense when an actual image, e.g. a Logo or photograph need to be placed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's worthwhile thinking about putting the image in a box and place it similar to the legend, using a `loc` argument. The advantage is that you don't need to care about extents and data coordinates at all. You also wouldn't need to take care of what happens when zooming or panning the plot. Further it allows to keep the image in it's original resolution (`zoom=1` in below code).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as image
from numpy import linspace

from matplotlib.offsetbox import OffsetImage,AnchoredOffsetbox


xs = linspace(0, 1, 100)
im = image.imread('arrow.png')


def place_image(im, loc=3, ax=None, zoom=1, **kw):
    if ax==None: ax=plt.gca()
    imagebox = OffsetImage(im, zoom=zoom*0.72)
    ab = AnchoredOffsetbox(loc=loc, child=imagebox, frameon=False, **kw)
    ax.add_artist(ab)


def multi_plot():
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(4, 1)
    for axis in axes:
        axis.plot(xs, xs**2)
        place_image(im, loc=2, ax=axis, pad=0, zoom=1)
    plt.show()

multi_plot()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You'll notice that the limits on the x and y axis have been set to the extent of the imshow, rather than `0-1`, which your plot needs to see the line.

You can control this by using `axis.set_xlim(0, 1)` and `axis.set_ylim(0, 1)`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as image
from numpy import linspace

xs = linspace(0, 1, 100)
im = image.imread('arrow.png')

def multi_plot():
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(4, 1)
    x = 0
    for axis in axes:
        axis.plot(xs, xs**2)
        axis.imshow(im, extent=(0.4, 0.6, .5, .7), zorder=-1, aspect='auto')
        axis.set_xlim(0, 1)
        axis.set_ylim(0, 1)
    plt.show()

multi_plot()
```

[image]

Alternatively, if you want to maintain the extra 5% margin around your data that matplotlib uses by default, you can move the `imshow` command to before the `plot` command, then the latter will control the axis limits.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as image
from numpy import linspace

xs = linspace(0, 1, 100)
im = image.imread('arrow.png')

def multi_plot():
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(4, 1)
    x = 0
    for axis in axes:
        axis.imshow(im, extent=(0.4, 0.6, .5, .7), zorder=-1, aspect='auto')
        axis.plot(xs, xs**2)
    plt.show()

multi_plot()
```

[image]